# Show and hide div in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I hide my page "section"  when I click on a button. and show it another button is clicked
Here's my code

```
import './App.css';
import Typed from 'react-typed';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='text-white'>
      <div id='index' className='index max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center'>
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
          <h1 className='md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6'>Roll</h1>
          <Typed 
          className="md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6 text-gray-400"
          strings={['simply', 'design']} 
          typeSpeed={70} 
          backSpeed={100} 
          loop/>
        </div>
        <p className='md:text-3xl sm:text-2xl text-xl font-bold py-4 '>best <a className='underline text-gray-300'>design</a> and <a className='underline text-gray-300'>simplistic.</a></p>
        <button className='bg-white text-black w-[200px] transition-[0.5s] rounded-lg font-bold my-6 mx-auto py-3 ring-2 ring-gray-300 hover:bg-slate-300  hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-white hover:scale-110 '>Create</button>//clicking this button will show the div below which has the id of info and hide this current div
      </div>
      <div id='info' className='info max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center'>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
      <div id='ino' className='info max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center'>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

how do i make the onClick event work it out?

Comment: This would be a part of some fundamental concepts of React.  Use "state" to accomplish this, then use functional component conditional logic to display or hide various sections of what is to be returned.  Here is an additional article showing how to do this where your "sections" are actually components https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-show-and-hide-reactjs-components.  The article also shows how to hide elements of your component. 
 In short, you need to read up on React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a `state` let's call it for example `hide` and set default value `false`, and on the button click turn it to `true`.

And you can conditionally hide the `button` section and show the `info` section.

```js
import "./App.css";
import Typed from "react-typed";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="text-white">
      {!hide ? (
        <div
          id="index"
          className="index max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center"
        >
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className="md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6">
              Roll
            </h1>
            <Typed
              className="md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6 text-gray-400"
              strings={["simply", "design"]}
              typeSpeed={70}
              backSpeed={100}
              loop
            />
          </div>
          <p className="md:text-3xl sm:text-2xl text-xl font-bold py-4 ">
            best <a className="underline text-gray-300">design</a> and{" "}
            <a className="underline text-gray-300">simplistic.</a>
          </p>
          <button
            className="bg-white text-black w-[200px] transition-[0.5s] rounded-lg font-bold my-6 mx-auto py-3 ring-2 ring-gray-300 hover:bg-slate-300  hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-white hover:scale-110"
            onClick={() => setHide(true)}
          >
            Create
          </button>
          //clicking this button will show the div below which has the id of
          info and hide this current div
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          id="info"
          className="info max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center"
        >
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <div
        id="ino"
        className="info max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center"
      >
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you check the updated code? need out a bit of help. Thanks.

Comment: how do i make the current section hide AND show another section right there?

Comment: Just updated, please check.

Comment: Thank you very much, tho i am getting some errors: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/916242216211595264/999732107733635152/unknown.png

Comment: You are welcome, Just updated, please check again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `useState()` react hook.

For example:

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className='text-white' style={{display: visible ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
      <div>
        <!--first part-->
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
          <h1 className='md:text-7xl sm:text-6xl text-4xl font-bold md:py-6'>Web</h1>
          <!--stuff here-->
        </div>
        <p>stuff here</p>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Create</button>
        <!--when i click on the button it will hide the first part(section) and show the second part -->
      </div>
      <!--first part end -->
      <div>
        <!--second part -->
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
);
```

You could check more details how to use `useState()` hook here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Could you help me out a bit on the latest code? a bit different and need a bit of help. Thanks